# When did the practice of having multiple series for a world begin?

Tags: manga-history

I have seen at least two manga where there are multiple series told from the points of view of different characters, but all set in the same world and at or around the same time.

First is [chrome-shelled-regios](/questions/tagged/chrome-shelled-regios), which includes:
 - Chrome Shelled Regios
 - Chrome Shelled Regios: Missing Mail
 - a couple of others

The other is [code-geass](/questions/tagged/code-geass) which includes:
 - Code Geass: Lelouch of the Rebellion
 - Code Geass: Suzaku of the Counterattack
 - Code Geass: Nightmare of Nunnally
 - a couple of others

Where did this originate and what was the first manga/set of manga to showcase this?

Comment: As I got no proof for this statement ill put it in this comment. I seem to remmeber that the multiple perspective's originaly started by animating game serie's (when they cry would be a good example of these) ill look around some more for definte sources

Answer (score 3):

It started at least 2000 years ago with works like Homer's Illiad and Odyessy, and lost works, Hesiod's Theogony, and later, Virgil's Aeneid, among other things.

Most notably, the Illiad showcased the seige of Troy, focusing mostly on Achilles's role and his dispute with Agamemnon.

The Aeneid focused on Aineas, who fought in the Trojan War, and escaped Troy to found Alba Longa, where the founders of Rome were from (they presumably descended from Aeneas).

It is also known that there are lost works about the Trojan War, which describe other parts of the war such as the sack of Troy.

Comment: The other part of the question is: "What is the first anime/manga to do this?"

Comment: @kuwaly that would make it a very trivial and somewhat silly question.  every bit as silly as "what is the first anime/manga with a love triangle in it" or "what is the first anime/manga who's title starts with the letter `k`"

Comment: I see no difference in validity between this and http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/399/what-particular-anime-first-showcased-crossovers  or http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4874/what-were-the-first-anime-and-manga-based-on-real-idols or http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4873/which-might-be-the-first-anime-and-manga-time-loop-type or http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3828/what-was-the-first-mecha-anime-manga-to-feature-combining-to-form-a-super-robot, all of which are considered valid.

Comment: @kuwaly Thank you for bring those to my attention.  I have downvoted 3 of them.  The one asking about the origins of giant robots, however, was fine because It **Was** asking about the origins of the trope, and not just `which anime happened to be the first to have x`

Comment: If you would like to add to this discussion about the validity/usefulness of these questions, here is the meta question: http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/738/are-what-was-the-first-anime-manga-to-show-x-on-topic.